# Overwriting an array in mongo using pymongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I have a REST api in python using PyMongo and I have a mongo object like so:

```
{ id: "123", items: ["a", "b", "c"] }
```

I would like to set 'items' to the array:

```
["d", "e", "f"]
```

How would I go about doing so without a bunch of insert and remove statements?

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite all `items` array, if it is possible in your case.
`database.collection.update({ 'id': '123' }, { 'items': ["d", "e", "f"] })`